OpenVPN: can't reach client network from server
I have two servers, beta and alpha; beta is an OpenVPN server. Both runs FreeBSD. Both runs jails.
OpenVPN network is 192.168.25.0/24. Beta's network for jails is  192.168.24.0/24. Alpha's one is  192.168.26.0/24.
Beta has 192.168.25.12 tunnel IP.
Config is fairly simple
server.conf
proto udp
dev tun
ca /usr/local/etc/pki/ca.crt
cert /usr/local/etc/pki/issued/beta.crt
crl-verify /usr/local/etc/pki/crl.pem
key /usr/local/etc/pki/private/beta.key
dh /usr/local/etc/pki/dh.pem
server 192.168.25.0 255.255.255.0
local beta
client-config-dir ccd
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 5
topology subnet
client-to-client
route 192.168.24.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.25.12
push "route 192.168.24.0 255.255.255.0"
#push "route 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0"

alpha's ccd
iroute 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0
#route 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.24.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.25.1"

alpha's conf
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote beta 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /usr/local/etc/pki/ca.crt
cert /usr/local/etc/pki/issued/alpha.crt
key /usr/local/etc/pki/private/alpha.key
ns-cert-type server
topology subnet
verb 3
push "route 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0"

From Alpha, I can ping beta's jails. From Beta, I can't.
tcpdump on beta shows outgoing pings; tcpdump on alpha does not.
firewall is open. Just open.
I do remember I've encountered that problem some years ago, but can't recall how did I fix it.
routing table, of course, seems to be correct.

Next time, first make sure that your ccd file matches your server's CN.
Just wrong named ccd file, nothing more!
